# Check if the website exists and if not then display Error message under the Form Input Field

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm fairly new to JS & React and I'm using React Hook Form
I have to check if the Website entered into the Website field in my form exists or not.
If the URL doesn't exist I have to show an error message as "Website not available" under the Website field which will get rendered using a FormError component.

[image: This is how it looks if Error is generated]

(This is a First Name field but since I'm using a common TextField Component it should work here as well)

So, I'm using "**url-exists**" package to test if a website URL exists and if the website doesn't exists it should generate an error as "Website not available".

I'm using this code to implement.

```
const websiteCheck = (value) => {
  let str = value;
  let message = "";
    let urlCheck = str.indexOf("http://") == 0 || str.indexOf("https://") == 0;
    if (!urlCheck) {
        console.log("Protocol doesn't exist!");
        str = "http://" + str;
    } else {
        console.log("Protocol exists!");
    }
    urlExists(str, function (err:any, exists:any) {
      if (!exists) {
        message = "Website doesn't exists!" //Just for testing
        console.log("Not available: ", str, exists);
      } else {
        message = "Website exists!"
        console.log("Available: ", str, exists);
    }
        // console.log(exists); // true
    });
  return message;
}
```

And I'm calling it as :

```
return(
.....
 <TextField
        key={fieldName}
        id={fieldName}
        .......
        inputRef={register({
            websiteCheck(value)
       ........
 />
```

This should ideally work but it's giving me "Not available" message in console.log() even if I enter a correct & valid URL.
And it still won't render the message I set.

What I found so far from debugging is :

1. When I submit my form my entered URL is accepted but it won't enter my **if(!exists)..else** block and I get "Not available" in console.
2. The second time it's submitting null value (or space idk) which enters the if(!exists)...else block and also says "Not available"

What should I do to get this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correct a few things here to make it work:

- you should use `<Controller />` when using a Material UI `<TextField />`, see this [section](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingControlledInputs) in the docs for more infos about it
- you need to use the `validate` function provided by RHF via the `rules` prop of the `<Controller />`, check [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) for all validation options (`register` and `rules` use the same interface for validations)
- `urlExists` uses a callback, so you need to wrap the call to `urlExists` into a `Promise` and set it as the return value of your `websiteCheck` function. Right now you are returning a string before the callback is even executed. The important thing here is to also make your `websiteCheck` function `async`, so that the Promise will get resolved (the `validate` function from RHF supports using a `async` function)
- it's also important to note, that you have to return `true` for the `validate` function if the entered value is correct. If not use a string for the error message

[image: Edit React Hook Form - MUI Textfield Validation]

Comment: Thanks!
I tried to make the URL Exists callback async but it didn't work for me. So I have't used this here.
I used the same above code in a dummy project to test and I'm getting required results, i.e., for Valid and Invalid URLs correctly.
Also I tried declaring **exists** as Boolean but since the package return a Boolean val itself I haven't done here.

Comment: Ok. I thank you misunderstood me, you don't have to make the callback `async`, but the enclosing call - in your case the `websiteCheck` function. Just check the CodeSandbox again, there you see that i used the `async` keyword for the `websiteCheck` function. And yes, the `useExists` function returns a boolean in the callback, that's why i passed it to the `resolve` function. I just wanted to let you know that RHF `validate` expects `true` if the passed form value is valid.

Comment: Sorry for getting back late. I tested your sandbox code and it's still failing for some of the URLs, like try entering https://google.com or other. It still fails for me. Although I tried https://codesandbox.io and it passed. I'm still puzzled how? 

Comment: I checked it and it is caused by CORS. If you open the dev tools while using the CodeSandbox you can see the following console error when you enter google.com: `Access to fetch at 'https://google.com/' from origin 'https://twwo9.csb.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` So it has nothing to do with RHF or the `urlExists` package.